# Deploy Outlook UserForm

Tags: vba, outlook

I made a userform to give out to colleagues.

The installation procedure goes approximately like this:

- allow unsigned macros
- open VB Editor
- add 2 references by manually navigating to the .ocx / .tlb files (needed for Treeview control)
- import form
- create a new module
- copy a procedure into that module (hook for button, contains essentially MyForm.Show)
- run another proc to create toolbar button
- save, restart

My plan was to make an install script; but I found Outlook's VBProject is sealed tight against any automated access.

How can I make that installation procedure simpler?

Comment: A VB6 COM addin might solve your problem, and it would certainly be easier to install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As microsoft wrote here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/290779/managing-and-distributing-outlook-visual-basic-for-vba

> *If you are developing a solution that you intend to distribute to more than a few people, you should convert your VBA code into an Outlook COM or VSTO add-in or an Office add-in for Outlook.*

Outlook macros are not made to be deployed so you will always have troubles deploying them to users as they will need to make too much actions as you described.

To avoid that, I recommend you to look at VSTO add-ins and ClickOnce. Here are the links:

**VSTO**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/getting-started-programming-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019

**ClickOnce deployment**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-clickonce?view=vs-2019

Comment: Wow, how did you stumble about my years-old question? Anyway, thats exactly what I ended up with (COM addin written in C#). Has been running fine ever since.

Comment: Haha I am myself turning from VBA to VSTO add-ins so I follow your steps! I thought it could help someone one day... Can I ask you how do you deploy your solutions? ClickOnce?

Comment: .exe file residing on a network share.... Just starting it shows the form "standalone". There is a commandline switch "/install", "/uninstall" that makes it (un)install itself (i.e. copy to AppData and write Registry keys).

Comment: Interresting... Thank you!